# Adding a child node to the first root node showing as last row in Guriddo Treegrid model

Tags: jqgrid, treegrid

I have created jqGrid TreeGrid (adjacency model) using Guriddo library.
When I add new child node to first root node, it is showing as last record in TreeGrid (on browser) instead of showing as child node under parent since this node's id value is higher than other records in database. How to display these kind of child nodes correctly under parent node when it is expanded. Please see the below image for this issue.

Below are the records in database:
[image]

```
ID   NAME         DESCRIPTION         PARENT_ID    LEVEL      IS_LEAF
==============================================================================

1    MGR          Manager             NULL          0          FALSE
2    DMGR         Deputy              1             1          TRUE
3    HR           HR                  NULL          0          FALSE
4    AHR          HR                  3             1          TRUE
5    SMGR        Sales                1             1          TRUE
```

The below is grid setup code:

```
$("#orgStrTable").jqGrid({
    //"hoverrows":false,
    //"viewrecords":false,
    //"gridview":true,
    url: u,
    //"editurl" : saveUrl,
    "ExpandColumn":"name",
    //"sortname":"id",
    sortable:false,
    "scrollrows":true,
    "treeGrid":true,
    "treedatatype":"json",
    "treeGridModel":"adjacency",
    //"loadonce":true,
    //"rowNum":1000,
    "treeReader":{
        "parent_id_field":"parentId",
        "level_field":"level",
        "leaf_field":"leaf",
        "expanded_field":"expanded",
        "loaded":"loaded",
        "icon_field":"icon"
    },
    datatype: "json",
    jsonReader : {
        repeatitems : false
    },
    colNames:['ID', 'Name','Desc','Enabled','Parent'],
    "colModel":[
        {"name" :'id',"index":'id', "hidden":true,  "key":true,sortable:false},
        {"name":'name',"index":'name'},
        {"name":'description',"index":'description',"search":false,sortable:false},
        {"name":'active',"index":'active',"search":true,"editable":true,sortable:false},
        {"name":'parentId',"index":'parentId',"hidden":true,sortable:false}
    ],
    "pager": "#pagingDiv3",
    multiselect:false
});

jQuery('#orgStrTable').jqGrid('navGrid','#pagingDiv3',
        {
            "edit":false,
            "add":false,
            "del":false,
            "search":false,
            "refresh":true,
            "view":false,
            "excel":false,
            "pdf":false,
            "csv":false,
            "columns":false
        },
        {"drag":true,"resize":true,"closeOnEscape":true,"dataheight":150},
        {"drag":true,"resize":true,"closeOnEscape":true,"dataheight":150}
        );
```

Database Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `org_str` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`description` varchar(500) DEFAULT '',
`active` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1',
`parent_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`level` int(11) NOT NULL,
`is_leaf` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Data Array:**

```
var dataArray = [
    {"id":"1","name":"MGR","description":"Manager","active":"true","parentId":null,"level":0,"isLeaf":"false","loaded":"true","expanded":"true"},
    {"id":"2","name":"DMGR","description":"Deputy","active":"true","parentId":"1","level":1,"isLeaf":"true","loaded":"true","expanded":"true"},
    {"id":"3","name":"HR","description":"HR","active":"true","parentId":null,"level":0,"isLeaf":"false","loaded":"true","expanded":"true"},
    {"id":"4","name":"AHR","description":"HR","active":"true","parentId":3,"level":1,"isLeaf":"true","loaded":"true","expanded":"true"},
    {"id":"5","name":"SAL_MGR","description":"Sales Manager","active":"true","parentId":1,"level":1,"isLeaf":"true","loaded":"true","expanded":"true"},
    
  ];
```

Comment: Which method do you use to add a node and how you do this?
Can you please post the grid setup and a way you try to add a node -
It is very difficult to reproduce every specific setup?

Comment: I have updated question with grid setup code and database table structure. At back-end, I am handling adding new node and inserting new row for this newly added node in db table.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: guriddo jqgrid version is 5.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after making changes to below grid options :

```
"sortname":"name",
"treeReader":{
        "parent_id_field":"parentId",
        "level_field":"level",
        "leaf_field":"leaf",
        "expanded_field":false,
        "loaded":true,
        "icon_field":"icon"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example works well and I think that you use addRowData to add a node instead of addChildNode method. See the [docs here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/treegrid/#methods)

The demo of your code is [located here](http://guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/support/jay/)

To add a node - select the first row and add the needed data. You will see that the record is added in the appropriate place

Comment: I am loading data from server side database. If a add any child node, I have to persist in this child node as last row in  database table and reload it again from server side.  did you use local data array or server side data in your demo?

Comment: I the example we use server loading, but local add. I think that the problem you have is in the way you save the new row in the database and reload it again. In your example your icon to add a new node is disabled, which means that you add a node your way. We can prepare if needed a full server example.

Comment: Yes, I am adding a node in my way and storing in database node details. Can you please prepare server example to solve this issue?

Comment: No matter if we use local data or server adding - the result will be the same. I think that you should use the methods addChildNode instead of addRowdata and after add it to the server you should pay attention how the data is sorted to grid - i.e to return correct the new resulting tree data. (not sure if I explain it correct)

Comment: Can you please explain how to use and where to use this addChildNode in grid setup? Please refer any documentation for this.

Comment: How do you add the node- with javascript, server side or...? Please specify the command or the method or the function? After add a node you should sort the records from the server so that they appear correct.

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to understand your comments.  To make it simple and clear, can you please show me any example/demo with local data with my data as it is? I don't want any add/delete/edit functionality. I just want to load the data into grid with type local. I have updated the question with data array.